# How to fix "fatal :unable to look up https (port 9418) (No such host is known)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I am trying to push using git using:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Here is my problem:

```
Fatal: unable to look up https (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
```

I ran `ping github.com` and got the IP, but I do not know what to do with them.

Comment: `git remote -v` ?

Comment: sorry for my error. I fixed it.

When I used `git remote -v`
it show me here

`origin  git://https://anhbui2904@bitbucket.org/anhbui2904/sample_app.git (fetch)
origin  git://https://anhbui2904@bitbucket.org/anhbui2904/sample_app.git (push)
`


Any idea for me?

Answer (score 5):

You have a wrong remote URL - `git://` is the name of Git protocol (port 9418), and it doesn't need to be followed by a different protocol name.

Try this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://anhbui2904@bitbucket.org/anhbui2904/sample_app.git
```

This will set your `origin` remote URL to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

if `git remote set-url origin` doesn't work, you may edit directly the

> .git/config

file, and repair the `git://https://` prefix to desired, git:// or `https://`