# fatal: unable to look up user@example.com:port during git clone?

Tags: windows, git, url, git-clone

I'm trying to access a source code from a Windows 7 host using Git 2.23.0.windows.1. I have to use a Windows host and `git://` protocol. Linux and other protocols are not allowed.

The error is:

```
$ git clone git://johndoe@source.example.com:22480/main
Cloning into 'main'...
fatal: unable to look up johndoe@source.example.com (port 22480)
(A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. )
```

I'm finding hits for similar problems, like [Cloning git repository Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14631594/608639) (fixed by switching to `https://`) and [How to fix "fatal :unable to look up https (port 9418)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56618221/608639) (push problem). But I have not found my specific problem.

I believe `git://johndoe@source.example.com:22480/main` is well formed according to the [`git pull (1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-pull) man page. See the section *Git Urls*.

If I am parsing the error message correctly, it looks like Git is not separating the user from the url, port and protocol. That is, *"unable to look up johndoe@source.example.com (port 22480)"* should be *"unable to look up source.example.com (port 22480)"* (without the user part).

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

---

`~/.gitconfig` is pretty boring at the moment:

```
[user]
    email = john.doe@example.com
    name = John Doe

[winUpdater]
    recentlySeenVersion = 2.23.0.windows.1
```

The only interesting thing is, the email address uses a dot  `john.doe@example.com`, while the user in the url does not `johndoe@source.example.com:22480`. This is how the system is setup.

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

> The native transport (i.e. git:// URL) does no authentication…

I.e. the URL should be `git://source.example.com:22480/main`. Or switch to a different protocol that does authentication. Try `ssh://johndoe@source.example.com:22480/main` or `https://johndoe@source.example.com:22480/main`.